# How can I set a specific sound effects to a specific volume?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, volume, flashdevelop, audio

I have a variable set

```
var vol = 0.25;
```

this var changes on demand and works fine.

In my flash game I have some sound effects on `movieclips` that sound only when the movie clips are being played.

I would like to set all of my sound effects to the same volume in one `as3` file.

Although I have my sounds playing in my timeline on `as3`, is there a way to get all of my sounds together on one `as3` file in order to set them all to a specific volume.

I was thinking about something like this:

```
var isSoundOn = true;
if (isSoundOn == true) {

    // get all sounds that i would like to change volume on
    // if in game play and any of the sound effects are ready - play all these sounds with my specific volume setting.

}
```

my code looks a bit like this but doesn't work

In FlashDevelop... My main Class...

```
public class Platformer extends GameLoop
{
public var redMonster:RedMonsterFla;
public var SoundFxVol:Number;


public function Platformer( )
{



}

    // here i have functions that open a popUp
    // inside the popUp i can change variable "SoundFxVol" with my volume slider  


    // here i would like to set my volume to some of my movieClips with soundFx

public function set VolumeForSoundEffects(value:Number):void
{
    // set array of movieClipsThatContainSound


    var movieClipsThatContainSound:Array = new Array( redMonster );

    var st:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform(value);

    SoundFxVol = value;

    for each( var mc:MovieClip in movieClipsThatContainSound  ) mc.soundTransform = st;
}

public function get VolumeForSoundEffects():Number
{
    return SoundFxVol;
}
```

}

I flash I have a movieClip called RedMonster with a library linkage to as3 as RedMonsterFla;
On redMonster MovieClip I have lots of labels, one of them is jump - this has a sound.
There is no code on the redMonster timeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your movie clips' `soundTransform` property to adjust volume of those sounds that are played within it. But, you cannot set a var and get all dependant `SoundTransform` objects to adjust themselves, so write a setter property function.

```
private var vol:Number=1.0;
public function set volume(value:Number):void {
    var st:SoundTransform=new SoundTransform(value);
    vol=value;
    for each (var mc:MovieClip in whateverArray) mc.soundTransform=st;
}
public function get volume():Number { return vol; }
```

`whateverArray` is supposed to be the array that holds all the movie clip instances that are dependant on setting volume here.

Comment: Im not sure what im doing wrong, I created my var var ( redMonster:RedMonsterFla; ) to connect to my library movieclip, i put redMonster in my array ( var movieClipThatContainsSound:Array = new Array( redMonster ); ) but it has the same loud volume, i traced my vol variable and that does change when i use my volume slider.

Comment: hi im pretty new to get and set functions, Where do i call them to make this work ? I have also updated my question.

Comment: You use a setter function like assigning a value to a variable, here you call `this.volume=0.5;` for example, this will invoke a setter function. Getter functions are used whenever a property value is requested, say `trace(volume);` will call the getter function. It's a long version of declaring a property with advanced capabilities like altering other stuff alongside setting the value somewhere.

Comment: when i open my popUp volume slider this changes the variable for the volume - i have traced volume variable and it does change but nothing changes to the sound of my movieclips. I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: I traced volume function and it works, I think my problem is that i'm am changing the volume before my game starts so the movieclip isn't on the stage yet so I need a way to change the volume of a dynamic movieClip, thanks for your help i'm halfway there.